# iReport - Concatenating two variables with different evaluation time

Tags: jasper-reports, concatenation, ireport

I have two variables

`$V{from}` has evaluation value set to **Now** and
`$V{to}` has evaluation value set to **Group**.

Both seems to be working fine.

Now I need to append them. Currently I have `$V{fromTo}` which has expression $V{from} + "-" + $V{to}. Its evaluation time value is **Group**. What I want is just to simply append the current values of the two first mentioned variables. The current expression gives me the result (e.g. from = 1, to = 45)

45-45

Seems like the expression is taking the value of $V{from} evaluated during group execution time also. Any idea how to do this?

(Note, requirement does not allow me to just simply drag the two fields, i badly needed to store it in one variable)

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved setting `Evaluation Time` to `Auto` in my Text Field.